# hide everything except div of id

Tags: css

I'd like to hide everything except div of certain id when printing but following code does not work.

```css
*:not(#printArea) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="printArea">...</div>
  <button>print</button>
</body>
```

Such CSS hides everything. It does not ignore the printArea. How can I achieve this? How can I hide everything, every selector except the one of id `printArea`?

Comment: It's also hiding the parent `body`, so yeah… You need to exclude all the parent elements that need to be visible as well, or otherwise redefine your selector to be more targeted.

Comment: You're right! My bad :D Forgot ignoring html and body tags. Now works fine. Btw. I don't know where the minuses come from. It's just a question correctly tagged and maybe some people will find it useful. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

`*` will apply style to all html tag present in the tag even body

the correct syntax should be

```
 parent *:not(#printArea) {
   display: none;
 }
```

```css
body *:not(#printArea) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="printArea">...</div>
  <button>print</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

What you are doing doesn't work. This is because you are setting the display property to all the elements, which includes the `body` and the `html`. `display: none` hides the element, along with its children, and thus when the body is hidden, everything on the page is too. To avoid this, there are 2 methods (off the top of my head) that you can use.

### Solution 1:

You can edit the selector such that it selects everything inside the body, but not the body itself. It would look something like this:-

```
*:not(html, body, #printArea) {
  display: none;
}
```

### Solution 2:

You can use the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property instead, because it doesn't affect the visibility of its children. This could look something like this:-

```
* {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#printArea {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*:not(html,body,#printArea) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="printArea">...</div>
  <button>print</button>
</body>
```